# Get only DataGrid Selected row to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I want to get only the DataGrid selected single row to DataTable. Below is my code

```
DataRowView rowSelected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
OrignalSelectedRow = rowSelected.DataView.ToTable();
label23.Content = OrignalSelectedRow.Rows.Count;
```

Problem is that `label23.Content` display total number of rows that DataGrid has.

My problem is simple and it is that i want to get only selected row from DataGrid to DataTable, But when i apply rows.count on dataTable it returns me total number of rows dataGrid have. It means that it is not copying only the selected row but a whole dataGrid.

please help me so that i can get only a single selected row in a DataTable.

Comment: When you call `ToTable` on the `DataView`, you get a new `DataTable` that contains copies of every row from the `DataView`.  Unless you have filtered that `DataView`, that means every row in the original `DataTable`.  Why are you calling `ToTable` at all anyway? `rowSelected` already is the one and only selected row.  Why do you need that in a new `DataTable`?

Comment: When i do DataRowView rowSelected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
OrignalSelectedRow = rowSelected; it gives me casting error thats why i used .ToTable()

Comment: If i try this code OrignalSelectedRow.Rows.Add(rowSelected); it gives me Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception.

Comment: please help me so that i can get only a single selected row in a DataTable

Comment: `DataTable.Clone` and `DataTable.ImportRow` would be the simplest option.

Comment: Please explain with example how to use DataTable.Clone and DataTable.ImportRow. as i think they cannot be applied.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i would be thankful to you if you explain it with a code. As i am not an expert.

Comment: You don't need to be an expert to read the documentation for two methods and search the web for examples. Try doing what you can for yourself first. Not being an expert doesn't mean not being able to do anything.

Comment: ok lpc no problem

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `DataTable` by clone the existing one and then add only the selected row to it:

```
DataRowView rowSelected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
DataTable newTable = rowSelected.DataView.Table.Clone();
newTable.Rows.Add(rowSelected.Row.ItemArray);
```

Comment: There's no point creating a `DataTable` that contains all the records and removing them when you could create an empty `DataTable` by simply calling `Clone`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: You still need to create the columns and these need to be the exact same as in the original table. ToTable() creates these for you.

Comment: Gee, if only `Clone` did that too. Oh wait, it does!  From the documentation: "Clones the structure of the DataTable, including all DataTable schemas and constraints".

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Right. You might as well create a new DataTable by cloning the original one. I edited my answer.