# Retrieve selected row from a WPF DATAGRID to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I want to retrieve a single selected DataGrid row to a DataTable, i have tried below code but it is not working please help me.

```
DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
DataRowView rowSelected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
OrignalSelectedRow.Rows.Add(rowSelected);
```

Please don't mess it with duplicate as i have tried different solution. And tried suggestion answer. But i got another problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get only DataGrid Selected row to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345851/get-only-datagrid-selected-row-to-datatable)

Comment: I am not able to get answer, i have been trying since morning, no one i willing to give me answer of my problem. Then tell me what should i do or where i should go, i have searched a lot over google but no solution.

Comment: I know it is not a very hard problem, but no one is trying to pay attention on it so what should i do instead of posting it again so that someone may get attention to it.

Comment: @Ash please try to help me to solve it.

Comment: you didn't even explain properly *what* is a problem. please create a [mcve]. you have only 10 views of your question, don't repost it multiple times. it is weekend, other developers don't rush to answer some vague questions

Comment: I tried to explain it as i could as long explanation also gives negative reputation, i am totally confused what to do. 
Problem simply is that i only want that the selected row of DataGrid to be copied to DataTable. Simple is that

Comment: My problem is simple and it is that i want to get selected row from DataGrid to DataTable, But when i apply rows.count on dataTable it returns me total number of rows dataGrid have.

Comment: @yaseenenterprises: What is the ItemsSource of the DataGrid and what is OrignalSelectedRow? How many datatables do you have?